# How to specify site folder for docker nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

When i start `docker-compose up -d` from project root (/var/www/buyer_main) nginx starts to serve on localhost, so I can see "Welcome to nginx!" message in browser. But id doesn't use project root to serve from. So I don't see /public/index.php run in browser. Where should I specify path to nginx config or root folder within docker enviropment? Here my docker-compose.yml file:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    pgsql:
        image: postgres:13
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
        environment:
            PGPASSWORD: 'postgres'
            POSTGRES_DB: 'postgres'
            POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${DB_DATABASE}", "-U", "${DB_USERNAME}"]
        volumes:
            - 'sailpostgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: webserver
      restart: unless-stopped
      tty: true
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      networks:
        - sail
      volumes:
        - '.:/var/www/buyer_main'
    app:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      image: digitalocean.com/php
      container_name: app
      restart: unless-stopped
      tty: true
      environment:
        SERVICE_NAME: app
        SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      working_dir: /var/www
      volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
        - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
      networks:
        - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailpostgresql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    webserver:
      driver: local
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected if you don't override the default nginx config file.
You can do this in the docker-compose:

```
nginx:
  image: mynginx:latest
  container_name: nginx
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./my-nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

You need then to provide the configuration for nginx in the new file `my-nginx.conf`

```
 server {
   index index.php index.html;
   root /app/;

   listen              80;
   server_name         localhost;
```

You can see a working example at https://github.com/Adiii717/dockerize-nginx-php